# TensorFlow You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'y_4' with dtype float and shape [?,1]

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, linear-regression

I'm a newbie on tensorflow and my first try is on linear regression. 
I read data from csv file
`taxi_data = pd.read_csv("taxi_pretreatment.csv")`

Then I extract column which I would like to work with

```
data = data[["distance", "virages", "prix"]]
data_array = data.as_matrix() # to_records(index=False)

X, y = data_array[:, [0,1]], data_array[:, 2]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
m, n = X_train.shape
u, v = X_test.shape

X_train_bias = np.c_[X_train, np.float32(np.ones((m, 1)))]
X_test_bias = np.c_[X_test, np.ones((u, 1))]
```

Then I launch the gradient-based algorithm

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
learning_rate = 0.01

X_data = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, n+1], dtype=np.float32, name="X")
y_data = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 1], dtype=np.float32, name="y")
theta = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n + 1, 1], -1.0, 1.0, seed=42), name="theta")

y_pred = tf.matmul(tx, theta, name="predictions")
error = y_pred - ty
mse = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(error), name="mse")

optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate, momentum=0.9) 
training_op = optimizer.minimize(mse)

n_epochs = 10
batch_size = 100
n_batches = int(np.ceil(m / batch_size))

def fetch_batch(epoch, batch_index, batch_size):
    np.random.seed(epoch * n_batches + batch_index)
    indices = np.random.randint(m, size=batch_size)
    X_batch = X_train_bias[indices]
    y_batch = y_train.reshape(-1, 1)[indices]

    return X_batch, y_batch

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        for batch in range(n_batches):
            X_batch, y_batch = fetch_batch(epoch, batch, batch_size)

            print(X_batch.ctypes)
            print(y_batch.ctypes)
            print()

            sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X_data: X_batch, y_data: y_batch})

        if epoch % 100 == 0:
            print("Epoch", epoch, "MSE =", mse.eval())
            # sess.run(training_op)
    # sess.run(training_op)
    best_theta = theta.eval()

print("Best theta:")
print(best_theta)
```

That code come from **Hands on Machine Learning with TensorFlow** book but I don't understand why it doesn't work

Here is the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1322     try:
-> 1323       return fn(*args)
   1324     except errors.OpError as e:

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(session, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1301                                    feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1302                                    status, run_metadata)
   1303 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py in __exit__(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)
    472             compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
--> 473             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
    474     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it stays alive

InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'y_4' with dtype float and shape [?,1]
     [[Node: y_4 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,1], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-93-7e2694bda819> in <module>()
     12             print()
     13 
---> 14             sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X_data: X_batch, y_data: y_batch})
     15 
     16         if epoch % 100 == 0:

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    887     try:
    888       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 889                          run_metadata_ptr)
    890       if run_metadata:
    891         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1118     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1119       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1120                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1121     else:
   1122       results = []

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1315     if handle is None:
   1316       return self._do_call(_run_fn, self._session, feeds, fetches, targets,
-> 1317                            options, run_metadata)
   1318     else:
   1319       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, self._session, handle, feeds, fetches)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1334         except KeyError:
   1335           pass
-> 1336       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1337 
   1338   def _extend_graph(self):

InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'y_4' with dtype float and shape [?,1]
     [[Node: y_4 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,1], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

Caused by op 'y_4', defined at:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 477, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 177, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 888, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 235, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 196, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 533, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2728, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2850, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2910, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-19-1a9e79400731>", line 4, in <module>
    ty = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name="y")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1599, in placeholder
    return gen_array_ops._placeholder(dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 3091, in _placeholder
    "Placeholder", dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2956, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1470, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'y_4' with dtype float and shape [?,1]
     [[Node: y_4 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,1], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

Could you help me to solve that error please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That code come from *Hands on Machine Learning with TensorFlow* book but
>   I don't understand why it doesn't work

Actually, this is not exactly [the code from the book](https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/blob/master/09_up_and_running_with_tensorflow.ipynb). If you look closely, in the book `X` and `y` are constants and that allowed to evaluate `mse` without feeding in any values.

After you changed the constants to placeholders, you have to carry them along, except for cases when the evaluated tensor doesn't depend on `X` and `y`, like `theta`. MSE obviously depends on both, so the solution is to do

```
mse.eval(feed_dict={X_data: X_batch, y_data: y_batch})
```

PS. What's `ty` in your code? Should be `y_data` there.

Answer (score 0):

You're batch genersting function is the problem, specifically, y_batch returned is not the correct shape, check what the shape of y_batch is, it should be (batch_size, 1)

Comment: I ran again the code and I notice that is the line **print("Epoch", epoch, "MSE =", mse.eval())** that triggers the error. Why please ?